# Errors in .NET build context which shouldn't be errors- partial migration from 4.6.1 to 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.1

We're working on porting a product which runs on .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET 6.  The catch is that it still needs to run Framework for legacy reasons, so we're multi-targeting frameworks.  There are thus some framework specific dependencies that we've added to each project and which seem to be working, at least for .NET 6... but the .NET Framework code is not cooperating.

We've been able to clear up all but the last set of errors. They all occur in the 4.6.1 context- so 6.0 builds correctly when we just do a Rebuild Solution but we still can't publish even when we only target .NET 6.0.  The errors are also strange- they act like basic references are missing (for instance, System.Windows.Threading can't be found) which should be present based on our references- for simplicity (and to clear up some dependency warnings) we're referencing the Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.Net461 nuget package.  Referencing the reference assemblies locally was causing a dependency warning so we cleared that up by adding the nuget package.

We've wrapped the Framework specific code in #ifdef NET461 blocks so they should **only** be referenced when we're building in that context, but the behavior we're seeing doesn't match that assumption.  What we're seeing instead is that in the context where we would expect the references to exist they don't, but they also aren't in the .NET 6 context so the #ifdef statements are doing their job.  Weirdly, if we #undef NET461 at the top of the files throwing errors, the errors in that file go away, but this seems a little squirrely and I feel like we're missing a better solution.  Doing the #undef should prevent those files from containing the necessary code but it might allow them to build...  It probably wouldn't **work**, but it would compile and run OK except for the functionality wrapped in those blocks.

We could refactor the code into a common, 4.6.1, and 6.0 projects but that is a major undertaking when theoretically our multi-target solution *should* work...

Our project file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Comm\ReadEventLogCommand.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Comm\ReadEventLogResponse.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Comm\UICommandFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="KeyedEntry.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="UIMsSqlAdapter.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Comm\" />
    <Folder Include="DeviceClasses\" />
    <Folder Include="EditCommands\" />
    <Folder Include="Exceptions\" />
    <Folder Include="Functoids\" />
    <Folder Include="HWModel\" />
    <Folder Include="LogObjects\" />
    <Folder Include="ManagerObjects\" />
    <Folder Include="UISchemas\" />
    <Folder Include="Services\" />
    <Folder Include="Security\" />
    <Folder Include="Schemas\" />
    <Folder Include="Visitors\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Experimental.System.Messaging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="3.1.0.600" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net461" Version="1.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.17.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.OleDb" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Xml" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core">
      <Version>3.21.70</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="IBM.Data.DB2">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\IBM.Data.DB2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The errors we're getting are all of the varieties:

The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
or
The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

where X is definitely in the appropriate namespaces, and the namespaces are referencing appropriate dependencies.

**Edit:**
My assemblies are below:

[image: List of assemblies]

Comment: "the namespaces are referencing appropriate dependencies" is nonsense.  References are controlled by project configuration, not namespaces.  What DLL contains these missing types.  I notice that you don't have any reference to `System` or `System.Core`, as my Framework-only projects do.  So I believe the build system is correct, those types are missing from your project references.

Comment: @BenVoigt Please see my edit.  System and System.Core are both referenced. 
 WindowsBase.dll contains the Threading namespace, which we use for Dispatcher primarily.  I've tried adding WindowsBase.dll explicitly (it's also contained in the nuget package) but there are no changes.  I've also tried explicitly referencing System.Windows with similar results.

Comment: With .Net Core, the System.Data classes were moved out of the main part of  .Net and are no longer available. Instead, you must install the Microsoft.Data NuGet package. There are a number of other changes like this. If you need old .Net Framework support and new .Net Core support at the same time, you may be better off maintaining two projects.

Comment: Does it work if you set single targetframework?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That seems to be part of the problem.  I think I'll be able to sequester the framework references from the core references so I think I'll be able to get away with multi-targeting- fingers crossed...

Comment: @jenkas It doesn't.  It makes all the same noises when I try- so I must be missing a reference somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem.  Thanks to the commenters who pointed us in the right direction.

Referencing the nuget package wasn't sufficient... the dlls within the nuget package *also* needed to be explicitly referenced.  Rebuilding *still* didn't clear out the errors, but Intellisense started working again so we unloaded the project and reloaded.  The final appearance of our project file is as follows.  Note that PresentationFramework, System.Windows, and WindowsBase needed to be explicitly referenced before the compiler would find the assemblies.  We also did some cleanup, moving packages between 461 and 60 that didn't need to show up in both.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Comm\ReadEventLogCommand.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Comm\ReadEventLogResponse.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Comm\UICommandFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="KeyedEntry.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="UIMsSqlAdapter.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Comm\" />
    <Folder Include="DeviceClasses\" />
    <Folder Include="EditCommands\" />
    <Folder Include="Exceptions\" />
    <Folder Include="Functoids\" />
    <Folder Include="HWModel\" />
    <Folder Include="LogObjects\" />
    <Folder Include="ManagerObjects\" />
    <Folder Include="UISchemas\" />
    <Folder Include="Services\" />
    <Folder Include="Security\" />
    <Folder Include="Schemas\" />
    <Folder Include="Visitors\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Experimental.System.Messaging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.17.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.OleDb" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Xml" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core">
      <Version>3.21.70</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="3.1.0.600" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <Reference Include="IBM.Data.DB2">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\IBM.Data.DB2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net461" Version="1.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```